# Ubuntu 20.04 sudo apt update The repository 'http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file

Tags: apt, updates

I using ubuntu

**Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**

**Release:     20.04**

**Codename:    focal**

I tried sudo apt update, previously no issue but recently I get this error as below

```
Ign:2 http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Err:5 http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Err:6 http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Err:7 http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Err:8 http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I checked the http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu, the url is not found.

Any idea on this ? I am newbie on linux.

Thanks

Comment: Why not switch to another mirror? (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) or the main archive? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories

Comment: @ArturMeinild tested with the link before, not working. Thank

Comment: @guiverc changed mirror work, may I know any issue if I change from my current country to main ? Thank

Comment: To switch to the main mirror (*instead of your country mirror*) just remove the country code from `http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`  (ie. remove the "*my.*" and you'll use the main site managed by Canonical (*company behind Ubuntu*) instead of your current mirror provided by ONBOARDCLOUD PTE. LTD.  The link of available mirrors was provided in my prior comment; you can use any; some are better than others; but all can have issues temporarily.

Comment: @guiverc noted and thank.